# Micro SD card not getting detected

Tags: sd-card

I have a micro SD card which run on my one 4 year old computer by inserting in the card slot directly.But on an one month old computer it is not even giving a beep of being detected.Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the new computer have a card slot or are you using a card reader with it?

Comment: Do you have all your drivers installed? Many of the SD readers are on USB headers and require them...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if it is being found in the device manager?

As this sound like it has been installed incorrectly.

1. If the device is in the device manager then try uninstalling the device by right clicking and uninstall.
2. Then right click to scan for new hardware.
3. Let the device drivers install.
4. Then it should work!

I hope this was of some help.